# Cant using back button within 60 sec after clicking admob banner on android

Tags: java, android, admob

I cant use the back button on android right after clicking admob banner for about 60 second. The back button is like disabled for 60 second. after 60 second has passed, the back button back to normally.

i've try to Edit on Android Manifest and App activity but still no changes. got stuck for 2 days and dont have idea anymore.

here my manifest

```
    <application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    
    <!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
               android:value="MyGame" />

    <activity
        android:name="MyApp"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".AppActivity$FirebaseNotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Here my App activity

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    AdMobWrapper.onStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AdMobWrapper.onResume(this);
    NativeAudioWrapper.resumed();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    AdMobWrapper.onPause(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    AdMobWrapper.onStop(this);
    NativeAudioWrapper.paused();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    AdMobWrapper.onDestroy(this);
    IAP.mBillingClient.endConnection();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (AdMobWrapper.onBackPressed()) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you consider revising your question to make it more clear? I was under the impression that you wanted to disable the back button after 60 seconds.

Comment: @Spectric please take it look again, sorry for my bad english

Comment: It's ok. We don't judge ;)